# JVM Exception handling flow of control

Tags: java, exception, controls

Sample code:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean continueInput = true;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number entered is " + number);
            continueInput = false;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Try again, enter integer only: ");
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    while (continueInput);
    }
}
```

The above program is to test the InputMismatch exception class. I am not sure at what point the flow of control is passed to the catch block when a letter is entered. Specifically, which scenario happens?

a) The JVM outputs "Enter an integer" and the user types in the letter B. Does the letter B get assigned to the variable number of type int, and then an exception occurs because of this incompatibility OR

b) The JVM outputs "Enter an integer" and the user types in the letter B. Does the input get checked first to determine if it is an Integer and if not throw an exception to transfer control to the catch block?

or

C) None of the above?

I think it is a bit of B and C.

Comment: Please use the `{}` icon when including code, not the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" icon.  I think you entered this as a JavaScript snippet, but Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: this is what debuggers are for.

Comment: Why are you asking a stackoverflow question for something that you can very easily find out by just printing the content of the variable?

Comment: An `int` holds only integers.  It can't hold letters, punctuation characters, strings, booleans, animals, etc.  So you can rule out (a)--it's just completely impossible and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextInt()` is defined as returning an `int`.  So it has to check the input and convert it to an `int`.  If it can't make an `int` out of it, it can't just return any old thing (like a letter or a `String`), because it can only return `int`.

In that case, it doesn't return at all.  It throws an exception.  The statement that called `nextInt()` is abandoned; nothing else happens in that statement.  In Java terminology, it *completes abruptly*.  If there were other methods that the statement was going to call, they don't get called.  If there was an assignment that the statement was going to perform, it doesn't happen.  That's how exceptions work.

And any statement after that statement doesn't get executed, either--they just get skipped.

In this case, the statement

```
int number = input.nextInt();
```

gets completed abruptly.  Since it's in a `try` block, though, the program then sees if there's a `catch` block for the exception.  In this case, there is.  So after the above statement gets completed abruptly, the program jumps over everything else to the first statement in the `catch` block.

If there were no `try` block, however, the whole method would be completed abruptly.  Then the statement that called that method would also complete abruptly, which could cause the method that it's in to complete abruptly, and so on until it's either caught or causes your program to crash with a stack trace.

Please try the Oracle tutorials on exceptions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) for more information on how exceptions work.

Comment: "completes abruptly".Thanks. This is what I wanted to know.